# 'npm start' command giving error 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND''

Tags: reactjs

I cloned a react code from github after importing  in Visual code studio while passing the command npm start as ending with error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/getPublicUrlOrPath'
Require stack:
- /Users/1448891/Documents/IWFY22-customer-feedback-solution/config/paths.js
- /Users/1448456/Documents/IWFY22-customer-feedback-solution/config/env.js
- /Users/1448456/Documents/IWFY22-customer-feedback-solution/scripts/start.js
```

and

```
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/1448456/Documents/IWFY22-customer-feedback-solution/config/paths.js',
    '/Users/1448456/Documents/EVOC_project/IWFY22-customer-feedback-solution/config/env.js',
    '/Users/1448456/Documents/EVOC_project/IWFY22-customer-feedback-solution/scripts/start.js'
  ]
```

can any one please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you ran `npm install` ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, you need to install the module first.

Answer (score 2):

Before running `npm start`, you should probably run `npm install` first.

The steps to run a project locally is usually described in the `README.md` file, so it is always a good practice to take a look at this file when starting to work on a project.